# Watin: Getting webpage from IE and launching JavaScript on it

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin

I'm trying to find opened webpage by URI and to launch JS on it. I found some samples and wrote simple method. That's how it looks:

```
private void GetHtmlCode()
    {
        string uri = GetTargetURI();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            IE ie = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(uri));
            htmlCode = ie.Eval(JavaScriptToRun);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Target page is not opened",
                            "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

And there's a method for getting URI:

```
private string GetTargetURI() //проверка URL
    {

        Regex reg;
        Match match;
        foreach(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
        {
            reg = new Regex(patternURL);
            match = reg.Match(ie.LocationURL.ToString());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
            {
                pageURL = ie.LocationURL.ToString();
                return pageURL;
            }
            pageURL = string.Empty;              
        }
        return pageURL;
    }
```

- so URI is completely correct or empty.

The problem is `IE ie = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(uri));` always throws

> WatiN.Core.Exceptions.BrowserNotFoundException: Could not find an IE window matching constraint: Attribute 'href' equals uri '%my_target_URI%'. Search expired after '30' seconds.

I've googled a lot, but still didn't find any solution :(
Can anybody help please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you just open web page using WatiN and then serach for specific object? When you have valid IE instance you can call something like this: ie.RunScript("alert('script started from WatiN!');");

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(u => u.Contains("NewMapping")))
```

And make sure your function is not returning empty, since this should be the reason why the windows is not being captured.

Regards!